# Changing the raster spatial extent in R

Tags: r, r-raster, extent

I have two rasters and I want to make the spatial extent of one to another. Then save it as a new raster. I used following code. However, I cannot save the 2013 images with new spatial extent as a new raster. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
raster_2013 <- raster("avgt2013.tif")
extent(raster_2013)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 112.91 
xmax        : 153.64 
ymin        : -43.75 
ymax        : -9 
> res(raster_2013)
[1] 0.01 0.01
> 
> raster_2015 <- raster("avgt2015.tif")
> extent(raster_2015)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 112 
xmax        : 154 
ymin        : -44 
ymax        : -9 
> res(raster_2015)
[1] 0.01 0.01
> 
> e <- extent(112, 154, -44, -9)
> 
> ex = extent(raster_2015)
> r2 = crop(raster_2013, ex)
> 
> 
> new_2013 <- alignExtent(e, raster_2013, snap='near')
> str(new_2013)
Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
  ..@ xmin: num 112
  ..@ xmax: num 154
  ..@ ymin: num -44
  ..@ ymax: num -9
> 
> rc <- crop(raster_2013, e, snap='near')
> extent(rc)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 112.91 
xmax        : 153.64 
ymin        : -43.75 
ymax        : -9
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `resample` function. You can use `writeRaster` function to save the file to disk.

Comment: `resample` would do the job but would be much more time- and resource-consuming than a simple `crop(extend())` chain given the two rasters are aligned here. `resample` should be considered as a brute force method to be used in emergency cases only ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, please [make a simple reproducible example to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

```
library(raster)

set.seed(11)
raster_2013 = raster(ext=extent(112.91, 153.64, -43.75, -9), res=c(0.01, 0.01))
raster_2013[] = rnorm(ncell(raster_2013))
raster_2015 = raster(ext=extent(112, 154, -44, -9), res=c(0.01, 0.01))
raster_2015[] = rnorm(ncell(raster_2015))
```

Then, there are several issues with your code.
In your case, `alignExtent` is useless since the two rasters have the same resolution and their extents correspond with regards to this resolution.

If your goal is to give the extent of raster_2015 to raster_2013, you need to realize that `extent(raster_2015)` is shorter (smaller) with respect to `xmin`, but larger or equal elsewhere. So `crop`ping alone will just affect `xmin` of raster_2013. You first need to `extend` and second to `crop` in order to have the exact same extent:

```
new_2013 <- crop(extend(raster_2013, raster_2015), raster_2015)
all.equal(extent(raster_2015), extent(new_2013))
#[1] TRUE
```

As @Geo-sp mentions, you can also `resample` raster_2013, but you would typically use this if the rwo rasters are *not* aligned (and be aware that it would, in such case, result in modified data due to the interpolation). Here, since they are, it would give the same result as `crop(extend())`, but it would be much slower and more resource-consuming:

```
system.time(new_2013 <- crop(extend(raster_2013, raster_2015), raster_2015))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.676   0.036   0.712 
system.time(new_2013_res <- resample(raster_2013, raster_2015))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 10.324   0.536  10.869
all.equal(new_2013, new_2013_res)
# [1] TRUE
```

Finally, in order to save it, well... you can use `writeRaster`, as reading the documentation would have lead you to ;-)

```
writeRaster(new_2013, "raster_2013_extent2015.grd")
```